# Get the status code of an XHR request with no CORS header

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

I'm trying to check if a page exists on the web. I don't need the content, just to know whether or not the page exists.

```
try {
    jQuery.ajax(link, {
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          jQuery("#moreInfo").html("not working");
        },
        200: function() {
          jQuery("#moreInfo").html("<a href='" + link + "'>Technical Details</a>");
        }
      }
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I've found that the browser DOES know whether or not it got a 404 response, which is all I need to know.

I've tried running the request in the console and found the following:

Internet Explorer: On a 200 response, IE 11 gives an error code of `0x2ef1`, while on a 404 it says  `0x80070005`

Chrome: A 404 response adds the following to the default no CORS header response: `The response had HTTP status code 404`.

Firefox: Logs the status code to the console if network messages are enabled - `[HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND 6ms]`

Is there a way to get this information in my script and check to see if the request was successful or not? Or is there a better way to determine whether a page exists client side?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get this information in my script and check to see if the request was successful or not?

Not with client side code.

The browser knows, and is happy to tell the user of the browser, but the same origin policy forbids it from telling your JavaScript.

You have to do this with server side code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check only if page is exist or not below way we use at our place.

```
function isValidURL(link) {
    var encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(link);
    var isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodedURL + "%22&format=json",
      type: "get",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        isValid = data.query.results != null;
      },
      error: function(){
        isValid = false;
      }
    });

    return isValid;
}
```

If it is present then function will return you true else false